# Workflow - Set Field Equal to the value of Another Field

Tags: community, workflow

I've two Date/Time fields on Lead object, Field 1 and Field 2.  Field 1 is be updated by our automated process and it gets overwritten every the process runs.  Field 2 is to store the first date that was populated into Field 1.

I created a workflow. The criteria to trigger the workflow is when Field 2 is empty and Field 1 is not Null.

Evaluation Criteria Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria

Then I do and field update formula: Field 2 = Field 1

This doesn't seem to work.  Any helps or advice are appreciated.

Comment: Try using every time created and edited and see its working....and let me know if does not work.

Comment: It works! What is the different between the two?

Comment: Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria :- it fires the rule criteria has to change to something else, then change back to the rule criteria in order to fire again.  So if you have the criteria of Active = true, you have to edit the record, change to inactive, save, edit again, and change to active for the rule to trigger.